ExcelWriter Mode append
The append mode of ExcelWriter does not work on my side. I am seeing that this subject on StackOverflow is quite old (1-2 years). Do you have any alternative ?
I have pandas 0.23.4 and I cannot update it (pro laptop)
thx

what are trying to accomplish with append mode?

I have a list of df, I would like to export them in an new Excel sheet, within an Existing workbook . with pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Docs\Excel To Automatize\Redemptions.xlsx", engine = 'openpyxl', mode = "a", on_sheets_exists = "replace" ) as writer:
df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Aggregate Table")
df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Aggregate Table")


for example, this does not work, it overwrites all the Redemptions.xlsx

you can export a list of dfs to an existing workbook like this:
rowPos = 0
with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
            for item in list:
            item.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='X', startrow=rowPos, index=False)
            rowPos += (len(item) + 2)
  

if that does not work for your case, you can also try something like this:
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Docs\Excel To Automatize\Redemptions.xlsx"
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode="a",engine="openpyxl", ) as writer:
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in book.worksheets}
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Aggregate Table")

